# How build correct SQL Query for group-select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

A problem with my low SQL skills I have. 
In table `Products`, which have structure `Id`, `Supplier`, `Brand`, `Article`, `Price` I must group all records by `Brand` and `Article` and select groups where specified in query `Supplier` IDs doesn't have lowest price in group or their price lowest than others more than 5%.

Tried with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Algorithm:
 1. Group all records by `Brand` and `Article` 
 2. Select only groups, which contains one of specified `Supplier`
 3. If in selected group specified `Supplier` doesn't have lowest `Price` or his `Price` lowest than minimal of another's by more than 5%, select that group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting the question as find all products for a given supplier where the supplier's price is more than 5% above the minimum price.  The language is a bit hard to follow, so this is my best guess.

If so, use a window function to calculate the minimum price for a group and then just use simple logic:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             min(price) over (partition by supplier, article) as MinPrice
      from products p
     ) p
where SupplierID = @SupplierId and
      price > 1.05 * MinPrice;
```

EDIT:

To get the `min()` excluding some suppliers:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             min(case when supplier not in (<list>) then price end) over
                  (partition by supplier, article) as MinPrice
      from products p
     ) p
where SupplierID = @SupplierId and
      price > 1.05 * MinPrice;
```

Comment: How I can exclude some supplier from MinPrice calculation? Without that I can't compute correctly.

Comment: @ArmanStepanyan . . . You can use a `case`:  `min(case when supplier in (<list goes here>) then price end) over . . .`.

Comment: So, min per partition will be calculated without records with specified suppliers?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're after, but if I read your question right, how about

```
Select * From Products p
Where price != (Select Min(Price)
               From products
               Where Brand = p.Brand
                 And Article = p.Article)
  And price < 0.95 *
              (Select Min(Price)
               From products
               Where id != p.Id
                  And Brand = p.Brand
                  And Article = p.Article)
```

If this isn't what you want, it should still give you a clue as to how to go about writing the correct sql for what you want...